# Using PagedResourcesAssembler with List<String> content

Tags: java, spring, spring-hateoas

I'm using Spring Boot 2, Springa Data REST, Spring HATEOAS.
I've a particular `@RepositoryRestController` in which I need to return a paged result of Strings. So I've not objects but a list of `String`.

This is how my controller looks like:

```
@RepositoryRestController
@PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()")
public class FrameController {
     @PostMapping(path = "/frames/{property}/groupBy")
    public ResponseEntity<?> search(@PathVariable("property") String property, @RequestBody(required = true) List<Filter> filters, Pageable pageable, Locale locale,
                                    PersistentEntityResourceAssembler resourceAssembler) {
        Page<String> pageResult = frameService.groupByProperty(property, filters, pageable);

        return ResponseEntity.ok(pagedResourcesAssembler.toResource(pageResult));
    }
```

The response looks like this:

```
{
    "_embedded": {
        "strings": [
            {
                "content": "BA0001"
            },
            {
                "content": "BA0002"
            },
            {
                "content": "BA0003"
            },
            {
                "content": "BA0004"
            },
            {
                "content": "BA0005"
            },
            {
                "content": "BA0006"
            },
            {
                "content": "BA0007"
            }
        ]
    },
    "_links": {
        "first": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8082/api/v1/frames/model/groupBy?page=0&size=20"
        },
        "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8082/api/v1/frames/model/groupBy?page=0&size=20"
        },
        "next": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8082/api/v1/frames/model/groupBy?page=1&size=20"
        },
        "last": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8082/api/v1/frames/model/groupBy?page=585&size=20"
        }
    },
    "page": {
        "size": 20,
        "totalElements": 11717,
        "totalPages": 586,
        "number": 0
    }
}
```

The response is quite ugly because each string looks like an object.

I would like to have a response like this:

```
{
    "_embedded": {
        "strings": [
           "BA0001",
           "BA0002",
           "BA0003",
           "BA0004",
           "BA0005",
           "BA0006",
           "BA0007"
        ]
    },
    "_links": {
        "first": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8082/api/v1/frames/model/groupBy?page=0&size=20"
        },
        "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8082/api/v1/frames/model/groupBy?page=0&size=20"
        },
        "next": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8082/api/v1/frames/model/groupBy?page=1&size=20"
        },
        "last": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8082/api/v1/frames/model/groupBy?page=585&size=20"
        }
    },
    "page": {
        "size": 20,
        "totalElements": 11717,
        "totalPages": 586,
        "number": 0
    }
}
```

I tried to create my own `ResourceAssembler` but unfortunately `PagedResourcesAssembler` applies the resourceAssembler to each item (String) and not to the entire collection.

Is there a way to reach my goal using Spring stuff?

Comment: Why would you do that? Embedded Resources are Resources and Resources are represented by JSON Objects. Changing that would make the result not HAL. Maybe these aren't resources after all, but just an array-valued attribute?

Comment: Exaclty @JensSchauder there are just a paged result of strings.

Comment: So don't make them embedded resources, but just attributes of your resource.

Comment: @JensSchauder Do you have an example of that? Thanks